# Update statement taking 10 minutes with large data set

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL stored procedure in which one statement is taking 95% of the total time (10 minutes) to complete. `#Records` has approximately 133,000 rows and `Records` has approximately 12,000 rows.

```
  -- Check Category 1 first
  UPDATE #Records
    SET Id = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Records WHERE Cat1=#Records.Cat1)
    WHERE Cat1 IS NOT NULL
```

I have tried adding a index to `Cat1` in `#Records`, but the statement time did not improve.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_C_Records_Cat1 ON #Records(Cat1)
```

A similar statement that follows, takes only a fraction of the time

```
  -- Check Category 2
  UPDATE #Records
    SET Id = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Records WHERE Cat2=#Records.Cat2)
    WHERE ID IS NULL
```

Any ideas on why this is happening or what I can do to make this statement more time effective?

Thanks in advance.

I am running this on Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Have you checked the execution plan?  What is the layout of your tables and indexes?

Comment: An index on #Records.Cat1 may be a good start.

Comment: please post you indexes.

Comment: @MichaelTodd, couldn't that potentially make the update take longer since the index will have to be updated also?

Comment: @abe, yes and no, indexes can also help inserts where other tables are involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update with join maybe

```
update t
set t.ID = r.ID
FROM (Select Min(ID) as ID,Cat1 From Records group by cat1) r 
INNER JOIN #Records t ON r.Cat1 = t.cat1 
Where t.cat1 is not null
```

Comment: This worked great!  Thank you.  One note, since my `ID` is a unique identifier, `Min(ID) as ID` would not work.  Removing the group by clause or adding ID to the group by clause are possible solutions.   I ended up removing the group by clause.

Comment: I wasn't dead sure what you were doing with ID in the select top 1, it seemed to imply the sub query could return more than one record and that you didn't particularly care which one it did, mo9n was one way of doing that, he shrugs.

Answer (score 1):

I would say your problem is probably that you are using a correlated subquery instead of a join. Joins work in sets, correlated subqueries run row-by-agonzing-row and are essentially cursors.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  That is exactly what was happening.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when you are trying to update a high number of records, sometimes is faster to use a cursor and iterate throught records rather than use an update query.

Maybe this help in your case.

Comment: That would work, but a cursor is the solution of last resort in sql. It's not avoid at all costs, but it is an avoid if possible.